# Programming * using only succ and pred

Tags: function, haskell, addition

How can I make a multiplication function using only `succ` and `pred`?

The function for the addition I already have:

```
plus :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
plus a b | a == 0    = b
         | otherwise = succ (pred a ´plus´ b)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This construction is hardly *special*. You just have to understand the basic logic of what multiplication is x*y is adding x to itself y times.

Multiplying x by 0 is 0

Multiplying x by 1 is x

Multiplying x by N is adding x to multiplying x by N-1.

Assuming performance is not an issue here so there is no reason to be tail recursive, a simple definition would be:

```
mul :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
mul x 0 = 0
mul 0 y = 0
mul x 1 = x
mul x n = x + mul x (n - 1) -- use plus instead of + if you were asked to
```

This can be further compacted - we don't *really* need the 1 case, or the zero case for both sides since adding zeros is just zero, and multiplying by 1 is x + multiplying by zero.

```
mul x 0 = 0
mul x y = x + mul x (n-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`plus :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
 plus a 0 = a
 plus a b = plus (succ a) (pred b)`

a goes to a + b -> b goes to zero

`mult :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
 mult a 0 = 0
 mult a b = plus a (mult a (pred b))`

this unfolds to a added b times.